# webview in eclipse is force closing on run

Tags: android, webview

i am new to android, so please dont mind if it looks silly to some..

HelloWebView.java

```
    package com.website;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class HelloWebView extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: James, do you have the `logcat` output?  It will helps us determine the reason for the crash.

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.website/com.website.HelloWebView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 19:04:04.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-02 19:04:04.542:  ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at com.website.HelloWebView.onCreate(HelloWebView.java:23)
04-02 19:04:04.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-02 19:04:04.542:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `webview` data member is still uninitialized in line 23. You do not assign a value to it until line 25. Simply move line 23 to after line 25 (the `findViewById()` call).

Comment: placed webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());   after webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");  and now its working...